# What is the black cloud that appears behind some of my characters?

Tags: ps3, rogue-legacy

Once in a while my new character will just have a black cloud, like dust or something, billowing out behind them. It doesn't seem to be associated to any specific traits or equipment that I can discern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens if the character you pick is a knave or assassin.

From the wiki:

> Both the Knave and Assassin have a black cloud following them. This has no function and is only for visual effect.

Comment: It seems like I've had it happen with non-knaves, but I could be wrong. I'll have to check when I get home... luckily I die a lot. ;)

Comment: Lol, well let me know how that goes.  I'll be interested to know if you've got a bug on your hands.

Comment: Yep, seems to be only knaves... don't know how I missed that before!

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got that figured out, then.